# Can't mock Spring `RestTemplate` exchange method with Mockito

Tags: java, spring, mocking, mockito, resttemplate

This is my tryout:

java

```
    when(restTemplate.exchange(
            Mockito.<String>eq("http://some.api.asmx"),
            Mockito.<HttpMethod>eq(HttpMethod.POST),
            Mockito.<HttpEntity<List<Object>>>any(),
            Mockito.<ParameterizedTypeReference<SuchenResponse>>any())).thenReturn(Mockito.<ResponseEntity>any());
```

This always fails with

```
org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.InvalidUseOfMatchersException: 
Invalid use of argument matchers!
1 matchers expected, 2 recorded:
-> at com.myapp.sst.base.app.service.ServiceTest.shouldDo(ServiceTest.java:62)
-> at com.myapp.sst.base.app.service.ServiceTest.shouldDo(ServiceTest.java:63)
```

However I used for every argument either `eq` or `any` so this error should not occur, right?

Answer (score 0):

You are using `Mockito.<ResponseEntity>any()` in `thenReturn`

here You should specify what mockito should return when restTemplate call occur, for example
`ResponseEntityBuilder.builderOK().build()`

maybe instead of mocking RestTemplate try using `MockRestServiceServer` with something like that

```
private MockRestServiceServer mockServer = MockRestServiceServer.bindTo(restTemplate).build()

mockServer.expect(ExpectedCount.between(0, Integer.MAX_VALUE), requestTo("http://some.api.asmx"))
            .andExpect(method(HttpMethod.POST))
            .andRespond(withStatus(HttpStatus.OK))
```